# What if anything does blue tape mean on a wire for a smoke alarm circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, smoke-detectors

Is there a common meaning amongst electricians for blue electrical tape on a circuit that powers the smoke alarms in a house?

Comment: How many wires go to the smoke detector? What are the colors of the other wires?

Comment: By "on a circuit" do you mean the tape is on just one of the conductors? At every alarm location? In the circuit breaker panel too, or not? I have a hunch it might be the interconnect/signaling wire that enables all alarms to sound when any one of them is triggered. The alarm may have a legend indicating the use of each of its conductors..

Comment: Don't know-- haven't looked. This is in a big three gang box that has switches and a number of splices across multiple circuits. The smoke alarm circuit is spliced in this box and that splice has a black wire with blue electrical tape on it.

Comment: @GregHill I suspect the same thing. Is there normally a voltage on that wire?

Comment: But if it were me wiring up the circuit in new work, I'd run a 14/2 to the first alarm, then 14/3 to the others with the red conductor as the signal carrier.  that doesn't appear to be what has happened in this case and I'm trying to understand how these alarms are wired.

Comment: @RibaldEddie I don't know about a normal voltage on the interconnect and it might be manufacturer dependent. There are some thoughts on the subject [in this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/16318/45928). As for /3 cable - that's what I'd do too, but it seems some folks would rather use a pair of /2 than buy a whole roll of /3 "just for this."

Comment: Yes, it is the remnants of the tape joint to the pull thru…

Comment: Pics of the wiring in the junction box and behind one or two of the smoke detectors may help us figure out what's going on. Also, make/model # of the smoke detectors in question and even a link to the installation instructions.